# $.getJson() Problem and returning an undefined value

Tags: json, jquery

I have a php script which produces the JSON object.

In my jquery I am using this code to call the php script.

```
  $.getJSON("/st/std.php",
   function(data){
    alert(data);
       $("myspan").text(data);
   }
  );
```

How Do i get the Data from THE JSON  Encoded in php File .In the form Iam entering some code which will perform the ajax lookup to a php file This is the Json Object iam producing it in php

Suppose if we input the "AAA" in the textbox it should fetch "AAA-ANAA".It should search the JSOn encoded object and fetch the label.

```
[{"label":"AAA-ANAA (PF)","value":"AAA"},
{"label":"AAB-ARRABURY (AU)","value":"AAB"},
{"label":"AAC-AL ARISH (EG)","value":"AAC"},
{"label":"AAE-ANNABA (DZ)","value":"AAE"}}
```

Comment: Change `/st/std.php` to `/st/std.php?name=value`, or add a `data` param.

Comment: Does $.getJSON("/st/std.php?term="+$("#txt1t").val(), function(data){ alert(data[0].label);}); popup AAA-ANAA (PF) at least?

Comment: I'm guessing the closing } in your JSON is a typo, right? Hopefully your php's actual response ends with }] instead of }}.

Comment: Iam Not able to get the JSON object Even.

Comment: There might be something wrong with the php code. Can you post it if you think that might be it? Do you get the JSON response if you leave the query string off your url?

Comment: Any Way I was able to solve it for my self  any way thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the response header includes:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

and not

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

In IE9 I had the experience where the data returned from `$.getJSON` was `undefined`, even though in the Network pane you could see the request being made and the response body containing the desired JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour. `$.getJSON` automatically calls `$.parseJSON(response)` before passing it to your callback. You can explore the JSON using Firebug, or if you already know the format of your JSON, you can navigate the `response` as you would an ordinary object, e.g.,

```
$('span').text(response.child[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

To see what ("object object") actually holds, replace alert(data); with alert(data.toSource());.

Say your php page returns {"a":"value"}, then $("myspan").text(data.a); would stick "value" in your span.

To pass a parameter, put it in the query string: "/st/std.php?param=value".

Comment: $.getJSON("std.php?term="+$("#txt1t").val(),
   function(data){
    alert(data);
    alert(data.toSource);
       $("#myspan1").text(data.toSource());
   }
  );

Comment: Is this the correct way of passing the parameter to php file from jquery

Comment: Looks right. But you changed /st/std.php to just std.php, and you left the () off the end of your first data.toSource.

Comment: @dave:Still getting Undefined value

Comment: Is your json well formed? jQuery's parseJSON function (which getJSON uses) isn't as tolerant as javascript's object notation. So, while {a:'a'} is a valid JS object, it isn't a valid JSON object. Run it through http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: $("#txt1").autocomplete({
 source: "/st/std.php",
 minLength: 1,
 select: function(event, ui) {
  var label= ui.item.label;
  alert(label);
  var value= ui.item.value;
  alert(value);
  $('#myspan').text(label.substr(value.length+1));
 },
 change: function(event, ui) { 
  if (jQuery.trim($('#txt1').val()).length<3) {
   $('#myspan').text("");
   $("#myspan").text("3 characters");
   $('#myspan').val('');
  }
 }
})

Earlier I used this code which I used to get the value and but autocompletion is spoiling my form so iam using $.getJSOn()

Comment: What is the JSON that std.php is giving you back?

Comment: [{"label":"AAA-ANAA (PF)","value":"AAA"},
{"label":"AAB-ARRABURY (AU)","value":"AAB"},
{"label":"AAC-AL ARISH (EG)","value":"AAC"},
{"label":"AAE-ANNABA (DZ)","value":"AAE"},

Comment: So, an array...Then try data[0].label, data[0].value, data[1].label, etc.

Comment: No It is not coming when i say that

Comment: Can you update your original question with more code, like the JSON response and code you've tried parsing it with?